# How to avoid disablement in jAlert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to keep the jAlert popup on the application but the application is getting disabled until the OK button is clicked. I want the rest of the application to continue running and not be disabled until OK button is clicked. How can this be accomplished?
The code looks something like this to validate User:

```
jAlert("Please enter a User Name", "Alert", function(){
         $("#workbench_user_ipad").focus();
     });

 jAlert("Please enter a Password", "Alert", function(){
         $("#workbench_password_ipad").focus();
     });
```

Comment: And what is jAlert?

Comment: jAlert is a simple yet feature-rich jQuery plugin used to create fully configurable modals, dialogs and popups with cool CSS3 animations powered by animate.css.

Comment: So why don;t you point us to the library. Not sure how it locks up the page since there is no sleep functionality in JavaScript. Also might help to show basic code on how you are using it.

Comment: The jAlert works something as explained in
http://code.runnable.com/UfNMPnKMU1ZgAACQ/how-to-create-custom-jquery-alert-confirm-and-prompt-dialogs